# Can anyone tell me why my triggers are not working the way I intended them to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been having this problem with my current game.

Well the problem is that when my player(Rocket) collides with Asteroid(Enemy) the player is meant to die and restart the level but that doesn't work even thought I have put my player with a box collider with no trigger and my Asteroid with trigger and a circle collider. I have also tried to put the asteroid with trigger and player with no trigger and both of them with triggers but my Rocket just goes through the Asteroid each time. There are no errors in the console window. And below is the code I am using for this.UPDATE: I used everyone's advice and sorted out the code looking back I should of seen that putting the "OnTriggerEnter" in the Update method wouldn't work but anyway the Rocket and the Asteroid both have a "Rigibody" component on the and when the player collides with the asteroid he disappears and doesn't restart and I have started writing a respawn point but the error that comes up is "error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'Transform.position' cannot be used like a method." This is the updated code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public GameObject character;

    private Animator anim;
    private Vector3 Respawnpoint; 



    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        switch (collision.gameObject.tag)
        {
            case "Enemy":
                Destroy(gameObject);
                break;
            default:
                //nothing
                break;     

        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Respawnpoint = transform.position();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        

        if (Input.anyKey)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool("Isright", true);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool("Isleft", true);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool("Isright", true);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool("Isleft", true);
        }
        else
        {

        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `RigidBody` on at least one of your colliding objects? `OnTriggerEnter` and the sorts only work if at least one is present.

Comment: Also. I Just read your code and I cannot believe, that there is no error message. You nested two functions in each other. That will definitely not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have pointed out the code is structured incorrectly.

Inside your update you have your trigger method. As a result it will never be called

Simply you need to remove the 2 lines of void update() and its following opening parenthesis. And the last closing parenthesis  for the method so the trigger method is on its own in the class.

Assuming you have a Rigidbody2D and have set trigger it should work.

I’d also suggest there is room for improvement in the code but rather than nit pick let’s address the main issue

Comment: Ok thanks for that feedback. I'm here to learn so if there are any more critiques please tell me as I wanna improve :)

Comment: Well. If you destroy the gameobject there’s not much point worrying about moving it. The code for moving it likely should be in update or fixedupdate. Or do you really only want to code to happen while it is in contact?

Comment: When the player interacts with the asteroid I just want it to restart. The asteroid will move in the future but for the time being I just want the player to restart when the asteroid is hit.

Answer (score 1):

You put the void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other) int the Update. Did you write it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem in your code is that your condition `gameObject.tag` is a little bit wrong. I suggest changing it to `collision.gameObject.tag`. Also, I think that it is better to place your  `void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)` outside of the `void Update()`. Please reply if this solution works.
Update: You can write something like this:

```
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 ...
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
 int sceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
    switch (collision.gameObject.tag)
    {
        case "Enemy":
        Destroy(gameObject);
       SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
            break;
        default:
            //nothing
            break;
    }
}
```

I suggest that you use `OnCollisionEnter2D` instead of `OnTriggerEnter2D` because triggers are usually meant to be invisible objects that you can go through.

Comment: Triggers would be right if you don’t want the asteroid to deviate from its course.

Comment: Depends if it destroyed it you might want it to continue on it’s path as a winner

Comment: I updated the code and it works but the only problem is that the player doesn't respawn.

Comment: You would have to add some additional code if you want the player to respawn. I would suggest you just load the level that was played again.